# Closed Form Solution for Implied Risk Aversion with Two Assets under Quadratic Utility

Tags: portfolio-optimization, utility-theory

So I believe there should be a closed form solution for *implied* risk aversion for two assets but I'm not sure how to get there.  Say you have Quadratic Utility $U$ on a fully invested portfolio of two assets ($w_1 + w_2 = 1$):

$$
  U = r_p - \frac{\lambda}{2} \, \sigma^2_p
$$

and given capital market returns ($r_i$) and vols ($\sigma_i$) for each asset and a correlation ($\rho_{12}$) between the two assets.

In a usual problem, you might be given the risk aversion ($\lambda$) and find the weights ($w_1$, $w_2$) that maximize the utility.  What I'm looking for is a closed form solution for the opposite problem of *implied risk aversion*, in other words given an optimal portfolio ($w^*_1$, $w^*_2$) what is the implied risk aversion $\lambda$ for a client that would want that optimal portfolio.

$$
  \lambda(w^*_1, w^*_2, r_1, r_2, \sigma_1,\sigma_2, \rho_{12}) =\,  ...
$$

**Edit**:
@KermitFrog reminded me that solution must still be an optimal one and then $\lambda$ can be solved for.  Giving the below:

$$
 0 = \frac{dU}{dw_1}
$$

$$
 0 = \frac{d}{dw_1}[w_1r_1 + w_2r_2 - \frac{\lambda}{2}(w_1^2\sigma_1^2 + w_2^2\sigma_2^2 + 2\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2w_1w_2)]
$$
$$
 0 = r_1 - r_2 - \frac{\lambda}{2} [2w_1\sigma_1^2 - 2w_2\sigma_2^2 - 2\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2(w_1-w_2)]
$$

$$
 \lambda = \frac{r_1-r_2}{w_1\sigma_1^2 - w_2\sigma_2^2 - \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2(w_1-w_2)}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes that is of course possible.

If you set up the corresponding optimisation,

$$
L=w^T\mu - \frac{\lambda}{2}w^T\Sigma w - h\left(w^T\mathbf{1}-1\right)
$$
and find the first order conditions:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda\Sigma & \mathbf{1}\\
\mathbf{1}^T&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}w\\h\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\mu \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$

you see that the solution is again the usual:

$$
w^*=\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(\Sigma^{-1}-\frac{\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T\Sigma^{-1}}{\mathbf{1}^T\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{1}}\right)\mu+\frac{\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{1}}{\mathbf{1}^T\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{1}}
$$

From here on, you can back it out.

Comment: So I admit it has been a few decades since I learned Lagrange multipliers.  Is \gamma above a standard formation?

Comment: It was a typo. I corrected to lambda.